# How can I add new observations to my dataframe using a for loop on Julia?

Tags: dataframe, for-loop, while-loop, julia

This might sound a bit confusing so bear with me. I am using a dataframe that gives all the details for the 21-22 English Premier League season. My project is to figure out how the amount of yellow cards a team receives affects the chances of winning. The dataframe has 20 teams and all 380 games from that season. My issue is that every team plays another team twice and the outcome can be different considering the amount of yellow cards each team receives and what the results were. (win, lose or draw). Because each team plays the other teams twice, my dataframe is short by half. If I am looking for the outcome based off of yellow cards for each game and each team plays a total of 38 games, that is a total of 760 games I need to consider. My dataframe is short by half. Now, instead of typing each game again, I would like to use a code to simplify things for me. I having trouble on how to approach it. Should I use a for loop? While loop? Any suggestions please? [image]

I have added a screenshot of what I am dealing with so that you have an idea. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: If you are okay with sharing a bit of data, display a couple of rows from the dataframe on the REPL, edit the question and copy-paste between two lines with triple quotes (triple quotes are \`\`\`. This is for formatting). Ideally, add an example of two output lines  you would like to get (even manually). This information would go a long way to help the community to help.

Comment: I added a screenshot of what I am working with. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Each team plays another team twice, once at home and once away. Both these games are recorded in different rows of the DataFrame, with different HomeTeam values.

Since there are 20 teams. Each team plays the other 19 at home, giving 380 games. A team's away games are recorded as home games for the other team.

For example:

```
julia> Soccer22[Soccer22.HomeTeam .== "Tottenham" .&& Soccer22.AwayTeam .== "Norwich",:]
1×22 DataFrame
 Row │ Date        HomeTeam   AwayTeam  FTHG   FTAG   FTR
     │ String15    String15   String15  Int64  Int64  String1
─────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 05/12/2021  Tottenham  Norwich       3      0  H       
                                                                                                        9 columns omitted

julia> Soccer22[Soccer22.AwayTeam .== "Tottenham" .&& Soccer22.HomeTeam .== "Norwich",:]
1×22 DataFrame
 Row │ Date        HomeTeam  AwayTeam   FTHG   FTAG   FTR
     │ String15    String15  String15   Int64  Int64  String1
─────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 22/05/2022  Norwich   Tottenham      0      5  A
```

To split each row into two rows for the home and away team, the `stack` command can be used:

```
Soccer44 = stack(Soccer22, [:HomeTeam, :AwayTeam]; variable_name=:Location, value_name=:Team);
select!(Soccer44, [:Team, :Location], Not([:Team, :Location]))
```

The second `select!` command reorders the columns to put the important Team and Location columns first.

Perhaps more column selection and renaming is needed to process this dataset but the `stack` bit is useful.